# How did I install version 15.5.1 of react-addons-create-fragment when the latest is 15.4.2?

Tags: npm

I just ran `npm outdated` in my project, and it claims I have version 15.5.1 of react-addons-create-fragment installed, but the latest version in 15.4.2:

```
Package                            Current        Wanted  Latest
react-addons-create-fragment        15.5.1        15.5.1  15.4.2
```

Here's the line in `package.json`

```
"react-addons-create-fragment": "^15.3.0",
```

Here it is in `npm-shrinkwrap.json`:

```
"react-addons-create-fragment": {
  "version": "15.5.1",
  "from": "react-addons-create-fragment@15.5.1",
  "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/react-addons-create-fragment/-/react-addons-create-fragment-15.5.1.tgz"
},
```

What's going on here?

Answer (score 1):

Version 15.4.2 is what's tagged as `latest` at the moment:

```
$ npm view react-addons-create-fragment dist-tags latest
{ latest: '15.4.2', dev: '15.5.0-rc.1' }
```

Higher versions (such as 15.5.1) also exist, but they are not tagged as the `latest`. Package authors can use [`npm dist-tag`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/dist-tag) to modify the `latest` tag to point to whatever version they want.

Comment: So they released a newer version of `react-addons-create-fragment`, which I got when I ran `npm update`, but they didn't/forgot to tag it as the latest, so `npm outdated` doesn't think I have what it calls `latest`? That sounds like either a miss by the React team or a bug in `npm outdated` to me, or what am I missing? *Edit*: Or possibly a bug in `npm update`.